# ProduceResponse from confluent cloud broker using confluent-kafka-python

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, librdkafka, confluent-cloud, confluent-kafka-python

This log is available with `debug=all` config in `confluent-kafka-python` producer client for confluent cloud.

How to parse `ProduceResponse` for `rtt`? Can it be done using `on_delivery` callback?

```
|RECV|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://b4-confluent-cloud-broker:9092/4]: sasl_ssl://b4-confluent-cloud-broker:9092/4: Received ProduceResponse (v7, 62 bytes, CorrId 31, rtt 323.28ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Message` object in the delivery report callback has a `latency()` method that returns the total time from `produce()` to acknowledgement from the broker.